# Can I upload video from iphone app to twitter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I create a video using images and audio file. Now I want to upload it on Twitter, YouTube and Facebook. I successfully uploaded it on Facebook.

I haven't found any exact link for uploading videos on Twitter and YouTube through my iPhone app.

I use xcode 4.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [ShareKit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) it's the simplest way to add social media support to your apps.  I don't think it has YouTube support of of the box, but I have seen folks talking about adding it.